# How to show preloader except when navigate between pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

The preloader/loading page is a whole page *div* with an *image* inside it. It works as an introduction page for my website.
I would like this preloader/loading page is displayed only under certain conditions and to fadeOut only if is clicked.

The conditions for the preloader/loading page appear:

- the first time the user enters the website,
- the user closes the tab and opens another one,
- the user is already on the site and refreshes the page,
- the user paste website url in a empty page.

When the preloader/loading page should NOT appear:

- I am already on the website and I change from one page to another

Is it possible create a preloader with those conditions? If it is, how can I show my preloader except when navigate between pages?

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<center id="splashscreen">
    <img id="splashcontent" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
</center>
```

**CSS**

```
#splashscreen {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 998;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
#splashscreen.show {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
#splashcontent {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

First attempt (problem: obviously the preloader does not appear at refresh):

**JQUERY**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function Preloader() {
    var preloader = $("#splashscreen");
    preloader.addClass('show');
    $('html, body').css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' })
    $("#splashscreen").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    $('html, body').css({ 'overflow': 'auto' })
    });
    }
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('doNotShow')) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('doNotShow', true);
    Preloader();
    } else {
    $("#splashscreen").remove();
    }
});
</script>
```

Second attempt (problem: the click function of the links does not work):

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var preloader = $("#splashscreen");
    preloader.addClass('show');
    $('html, body').css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' })
    $("#splashscreen").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    $('html, body').css({ 'overflow': 'auto' })
    });
    $("a").click(function(){
    $("#splashscreen").hide();
    });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: When user clicked link to another page, store information in `localStorage` about what page it's expected to show. When page opened, check the information and delete it from the `localStorage`. This might fail if user opened link in a new tab/window though, but you can also check `history.length` which will be `1` if it's a new tab

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Probably I'm wrong but when I check localStorage information I don't see any difference from start browser and change page. When I found the information to delete how can I insert it in my code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question...the information in localstorage is meant to be single use and only when user clicked link to another page, that's why it needs to be deleted. It also can contain date, so it can also "expire" after _nn_ seconds.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain better. All I see are key:`doNotShow` and value:`true` on Session Storage. I was wondering how can I delete Storage information with the code. I tried using this code `$(window).unload(function(){
sessionStorage.removeItem("doNotShow");
});` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Because you are trying remove the item in `unload` event, not in `onload`

Comment: It works but even when I change to another page. Is there any way I can clear Storage only for refresh page and not for change page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add event listener on all links to different pages. In that listener, use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to store url of the link.

When page loaded, check for data in the `sessionStorage`, if it's present and matches current url and `history.length` is larger then 1, don't use preloader page. Delete data from `sessionStorage` so it won't be used again if page refreshed.

Here is an example

```
let status = "page opened for the first time, refreshed or opened in a new window/tab";

const storageName = "clickedLink";
const storageData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(storageName));
if (storageData !== null)
{
  if (storageData.url == location.href && history.length != 1)
  {
    status = "new page loaded";
  }
  else
  {
    status = "page refreshed or expired";
  }

  sessionStorage.removeItem(storageName);
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", onClickPage);

function onClickPage(e)
{
  const el = e.target;
  //because we are listening clicks on body, make sure we process only <a href=...> elements
  if (el.tagName != "A" || el.href.match(/#reload$/))
    return;

  //store information about the click
  sessionStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify({
    url: el.href,
    dateClicked: new Date()
  }));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ybhnz5x9

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @vanowm ! It works!! I insert in the `if (storageData.url == location.href && history.length != 1)` the preloader remove statement and above your code I insert my code for display always the preloader. I don't know why but when I insert some code in the `else`, it doesn't return any code I put.

Comment: The `else` statement would probably never be true, unless `localStorage` used instead of `sessionStorage` and user clicked a link and closed browser before it had chance open the page. In fact, "page refreshed or expired" is not accurate description, there is no actual date check implemented. So, you can just remove it, I can't think of any scenario when `else` could be triggered

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that it works perfectly on codepen and in your JSFiddle example in all browser. Unfortunately it doesn't work well on my website when I am using firefox and safari.

Comment: The codepan and jsfiddle is not good indicator if it works or not, they use iframes.